# Why opening a folder via a shortcut makes Audacious to start?

Tags: mount, directory, audacious

I have very recently decided to use Ubuntu Mate. I installed Audacious and whenever I open a folder via its shortcut (placed in the panel) Audacious runs by itself and starts to scan the folder opened. I wish I could stop it doing it, but I've have not succeeded. Would you help me find the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the very subtle fact I had not any vision of. I had used `Open with other application...` on a folder by a right click to make `Audacious` enqueu the music files inside of it and start playing them. It must have been one of the times that I had forgotten to remove `Remember this application for "folder" files` option and the system started to open `Audacious` every time I tried to mount a drive.
To fix the issue I ordered the system to open folders by Caja and the system is now working perfectly fine.